# Improve performance of SQL Query to select ids from different tables in multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, performance

Let us just imagine I have the following table structure

Table: images

```
id   path   

1    x  
2    x  
3    x  
4    x  
5    x  
6    x  
7    x  
8    x
```

Table: user

```
id    image imageSmall

1     1     1
2     2     2
3     4     4
```

Table: books

```
id    image imageSmall

1     5     5
2     6     6
3     8     8
```

I now want to get the ID of every image used in other tables. I made this query here

```
SELECT id FROM images WHERE id IN (SELECT image FROM user) OR id IN (SELECT imageSmall FROM user) OR id IN (SELECT image FROM books) OR id IN (SELECT imageSmall FROM books);
```

The problem I see here, is that, when I have a large amount of data, this query could be very time consuming and not performant at all because of the many `IN` parts of the query. Is there a way to improve the performance of this query?

Comment: What about this? I do not tested, jutst try it: `SELECT DISTINCT id FROM images WHERE id IN (SELECT image FROM user UNION SELECT imageSmall FROM user UNION SELECT image FROM books UNION SELECT imageSmall FROM books);`

Comment: Every subselect can be rewritten into a JOIN. However, MySQL optimizer is good enough to be smart about what it has to do. That means you need to see whether the scenario you imagined even exists. Create a lot of records and then measure the performance of your query. Use `EXPLAIN` to see what MySQL does and if it really consumes time - then it's time to optimize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would phrase this using `exists` rather than `in`:

```
SELECT id
FROM images i
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user u WHERE u.image = i.id) OR
      EXiSTS (SELECT 1 FROM user u WHERE u.imageSmall = i.id) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM books b WHERE b.image = i.id);
```

For performance, be sure that you have the following indexes:

```
create index idx_user_image on user(image);
create index idx_user_imageSmall on user(imageSmall);
create index idx_books_image on books(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use joins instead of that many select in selects, and DISTINCT to return unique values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(i.id) FROM images i 
INNER JOIN `user` u 
INNER JOIN `books` b 
WHERE b.image=i.id OR b.imageSmall=i.id OR u.image=i.id OR u.imageSmall=i.id
```